# Bison Error in the calculator example

Tags: bison, yacc

I am learning bison through the standard calculator example, where I am trying to add some new functionalities to already written calculator. I am trying to add a feature to my calc where a+1 = b would work.

in my .y file I have to declare terminal symbols :

```
%token <symbol> SYMBOL_NAME
%token <dval> NUMBER
%token LIST_VAR_COMMAND
%token LIST_CONST_COMMAND
%token LIST_FUNC_COMMAND
%token DELETE_COMMAND
%token QUIT_COMMAND
%token CLEAR_COMMAND
%token BINARY
%token OCTAL
%token DECIMAL
%token HEXADECIMAL
%token UNSIGNED
%token CHAR
%token SHORT
%token INT
%token LONG
%token FOR
```

I declare my statement to be like :

```
statement:      ';'
|       expression             { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 0); }
|       expression BINARY      { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 2); }
|       expression OCTAL       { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 8); }
|       expression DECIMAL     { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 10); }
|       expression HEXADECIMAL { setp($1); print_universal_base($1, 16); }
```

I declare my expression to be like :

```
expression:     expression ',' expression { $$ = $3; }
|       NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
|       CHAR { $$ =(int)$1; }
```

I get an error in line

```
|       CHAR { $$ =(int)$1; }
```

saying : $1 of `expression' has no declared type

what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the value of some symbol from the rule, that symbol needs to have a type, and its value needs to be set properly.  So for the rule

```
expression: CHAR { $$ = $1; }
```

to work, `CHAR` needs to have a defined type, for example:

```
%token<dval> CHAR
```

and the lexer needs to provide the value in `yylval.dval` when it returns a `CHAR` token.  Now depending on what you want the input `a+1=b` to actually do, (and assuming the lexer returns `CHAR` for `a` and `b` and not `SYMBOL`) this may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Casting the value $1 to (int) is usually not how you do this. You need to declare that 'expression' has a certain type, thus bison knows what part of the union it needs to assign. Just try:

```
%type <dval> expression
```